# Python - Create Column based on max date in Multi Index DF

Tags: python, pandas, date, max, multi-index

I have a Multi Index dataframe and the first index is a datetime index. I want to find the maximum date from the date index and then create a new column with that value.

I'm able to find the max date by using:

```
    df.index.max()

    (Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00'), 'c')
```

When I try and create a new column with this date, I get an error that says, "Length of values does not match length of index":

```
 df['maxdate'] = df.index.max()
```

This is how the table currently is:

[image: This is how it currently is]

This is how I want the table to look:

[image]

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Only a small change needed!

Change this

`df['maxdate'] = df.index.max()`

to:

`df['maxdate'] = df.index.max()[0]`

Calling `df.index.max()` returns a tuple with two objects, the date and company. Since you want to use just the date, you have to access that since it's the first item.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it had to be something simple, i just couldn't figure it out.